# Override global body parser for a single route in Express

Tags: javascript, express, body-parser

Using Express 4.18

I have an app that uses a global body parser of json.  I would like to override a single route with a raw parser.  I've tried several configurations, but json always seems to take precedence over raw.

Example of what I was hoping would work, but does not.

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

// Apply json parser globally.
app.use(express.json())

// This uses the global json parser.
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  // Here, req.body is the JSON request body parsed into a Javascript object as expected.
})

// I was hoping to override the global json parser for this one endpoint.
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: "application/json"}), function (req, res) {
  // Here, req.body still seems to be a parsed JSON object not a Buffer.
})
```

If I remove the global json parser, the webhook req.body becomes a Buffer as expected.

This isn't a big deal with two endpoints, but the app has dozens and I was hoping to avoid applying parsers to every single one as the docs suggest in order to reduce the chance of introducing bugs.

Is it possible to override a single endpoint's body parser?

Comment: I think you'll need to put the `app.post('/webhook', …)` call for creating the endpoint *before* the `app.use(express.json())` middleware

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I guess this is the problem with trivial examples -- that would work here, but in real life our app is pretty big with many different routes and route handlers.  I was hoping to override the global rather than add a bunch of exceptions to our app creation code, but it's really not looking possible.

Comment: You mean you have nested routers? And there is a global bodyparser middleware applying to all of them, and now you want to exempt a single nested route?

Comment: I think this is not possible because your mounted middleware runs before any route handler. But you can write a custom middleware that checks the requested it, if it matches the route you wand to handle with the raw parsers, just call `next`, if its any other route, call the json middleware. This should just be a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

it's unfortunate that Express doesn't provide a simpler way to override global middleware. One alternative could be to create a custom middleware that checks the route and applies the appropriate parser. Here's a simple example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var jsonParser = express.json();
var rawParser = express.raw({type: "application/json"});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.path === '/webhook') {
    return rawParser(req, res, next);
  }
  jsonParser(req, res, next);
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  // Here, req.body is the JSON request body parsed into a Javascript object as expected.
});

app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
  // Here, req.body will be a Buffer.
});

// Other routes here...
```

Answer (score -2):

This looks like Stripe, right?
I deal with this myself some time ago.

The way I solved it was by changing the request to buffer before verifying the signature from Stripe.

```
 const raw = new Buffer.from(request.body);
 event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          raw,
          signature,
          endpointSecret
        );
```